# simplifying binomial coefficient calculation

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I am trying to reduce the calculation for the following binomial sum:

```
def binomial(m, k):
    result = 1
    for i in range(k):
        result = result * (m - i) / (i + 1)
    return result

n, t = 10, 20
bin2 = binomial(n + t, n)
for i in xrange(n + 1):
    bin2 = binomial(n + t - i, n)    # recalculation here. 
    # bin2 = bin2 * (t - i) / (n + t - i) my wrong implementation
    print bin2
```

what I do not like here is that bin2 is recalculated all the time during the loop, when I should have used previously calculated bin2. I understand that I have to use formula from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) [image],

but my wrong implementation give incorrect result. Any idea how should I simplify it?

Comment: Can't you just memoize the results?

Comment: @mu無 this is exactly what I am trying to do, but all I need there is to remember the previous one calculation

Comment: Well then just pass it as an argument, `for i in xrange(n+1): bin2 = binomial(n + t - i, n, bin2)`, and within your method, do `result = bin2 * 1 / k`.

Comment: @mu無 not really sure what are you doing: binomial is taking 2 parameters, in you code you are passing 3.

Comment: That's exactly what I am saying, pass 3 arguments to binomial instead of 2, the third one being the previous value of bin.

Comment: why you dont use `yield` instead of `return` in `binomial` function to have a iterator ?

Comment: @Kasra how would yield help me to achieve my goal?

Comment: @SalvadorDali i add it in answer , with `yield` the result of your function is an iterator that contain all the binomials for a number, then you can use it in your code by just go in your iterator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error. Print before updating.

```
def binomial(m, k):
    result = 1
    for i in range(k):
        result = result * (m - i) / (i + 1)
    return result

n, t = 10, 20
bin2 = binomial(n + t, n)
for i in xrange(n + 1):
    print bin2
    bin2 = bin2 * (t - i) / (n + t - i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yield` instead of `return` in binomial function to have a **iterator** contain all the binomials for your number :

```
>>> def binomial(m, k):
...     result = 1
...     for i in range(k):
...         result = result * (m - i) / (i + 1)
...         yield result
... 
>>> list(binomial(6,3))
[6, 15, 20]
```

And then when you want to calculate the `bin(30,10)` till `bin(20,10)` based on your for loop you can just slice the list and reverse it :

```
>>> list(binomial(n,t))[-t:][::-1]
```

Comment: the problem is that I want to start from a particular binomial (30, 10) and in your case I will be starting from (0, ...) and iterating further.

Comment: if you want to start from end you can just reverse the list !

Comment: I think you are missing the point. I know how yield is working and what iterators are. The problem is that your method calculates all binomials in range starting from 0. I do not want it, because I to start from some number in the middle. Try to modify your example to work with the starting point I provided to understand what I am talking about.

Comment: do you say that you want `bin(30,10)` ... `bin(20,10)` ?

Comment: I think it was clear from my starting code what exactly do I want to calculate. I tried to show an exact example

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function attribute to hold the previous result and use it in the function's calcs:

```
def foo(n):
    x = foo.previous + n
    foo.previous = x
    return x

foo.previous = 0

for n in xrange(5):
    print foo.previous, foo(n)

>>> 
0 0
0 1
1 3
3 6
6 10
>>>
```

Or use a decorator:

```
import functools
def wraps(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            p = f.previous
        except AttributeError as e:
            p = 0
        kwargs['previous'] = p
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        f.previous = result
        return result
    return wrapper

@wraps
def foo(n, previous = None):
    return n + previous

>>> 
>>> foo(2)
2
>>> foo(2)
4
>>> foo(2)
6
>>> foo(2)
8
>>>
```